# Units of vaiance when variable is in %.

Tags: statistics

I have some confusion here. If some random variable is measured in some units, say $kg$
then clearly it's variance is measured in $kg^2$. But if the variable is dimensionless 
and measured say in  $\%$ or base points in what unit the variance is measured? $\%^2$?
Does it make sense?. It seems for me a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not always useful to think of variance in units, since it can get confusing at some point. You have to remember variance is a measure that tells you how far a set of numbers is spread out, and by numbers  it means we can practically use it on anything even if they don´t have dimensions ( a  %  is still number ). So rather than seeing it as a squared percentage try to visualize it as how far the %´s  you get on your experiment are from each other.

Comment: I understood your point. However, we do need remember about units using variance in some formulas to avoid senseless results and adjust certain parameters accordingly.